# setup proxy to docker containers from java application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker, proxy

Need help with technical solution.

I have java (spring boot) application which may start docker container. Application assign ID and port to each container. That port is used as separate UI. ID is used to stop container.

For now, application work with 443 secured port, while each container open it own port in a range 19000-19100.

Is it possible to setup something like proxy server in application, verify request and then forward it to container?

Let's say, instead of `myhost.com:19000` I want to use `myhost.com/container/{containerId}`?

I'm thinking about rest template or feign client, but not sure how it will behave with websockets. Any thoughts? Existing tools or libraries?

Comment: I know, it is not java, but you are searching for this, just a java implementation: https://github.com/ThreeMammals/Ocelot

Comment: thx, looks promising.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Spring Cloud Netflix Zuul](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi__router_and_filter_zuul.html).

I am working on a project where we use this to proxy requests from frontend to a service which handles persistence processes.

Maybe it will help you achieve what you are looking for.

Comment: Thx, I found it supports dynamic proxying